# ManActivity + fragment difference at launch

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, stack-trace

I am building an Android app with feature modules at the same level as my `app` application module, and to take inspiration I am looking at some online repos.

Copying one of them I noticed a slight difference in the lifecycle of my app startup.
We both have a manifest with only `MainActivity` in it and we both have the MainActivity layout made of a `BottomNavigationView` and a `fragment` field containing a `NavHostFragment` referencing the same navGraph.
Then we both have the fragment (`StartFragment`) referenced in our navigation xml file with a layout containing a simple text field.

All basically looks the same but in my case the `StartFragment` goes through its `onViewCreated` as soon as the Activity reaches `setContentView` whereas in the project I am getting inspiration from that occurs when the Activity is done with its `onCreate`

I am comparing the two stack traces dumped on the `StartFragment.onViewCreated` and they look different, but I have no idea what could be causing it.

```
MY STACKTRACE

java.lang.Throwable: stack dump
 at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:490)
 at com.mypetproject.StartFragment.onViewCreated(StartFragment.kt:19)
 at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2987)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3126)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:3063)
 at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2988)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:392)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:281)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:140)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:319)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:298)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
 at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
 at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
 at com.mypetproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:18)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

---

```
OTHER PROJECT STACKTRACE

java.lang.Throwable: stack dump
 at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:490)
 at bg.dihanov.commonui.StartFragment.onViewCreated(StartFragment.kt:19)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:332)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2625)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2577)
 at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2722)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.activityCreated(FragmentStateManager.java:346)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1188)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2625)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2577)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:247)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:541)
 at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:210)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
 at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5953)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

P.s. Both apps were launched on an emulator running Android 21 and both projects have same versions for dependencies, plugins, gradle wrapper, etc.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours spent investigating this issue I found out that it was due to a dependency I had in my project that was not present in the one I was taking inspiration from.

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.3'
```

So beware because apparently this extra dependency modifies the lifecycle/behaviour of Activity/Fragment pairs